# Handle graceful termination of pod in Kubernetes in multi-container scenario

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

There is a situation where there are 2 containers within the pod and one takes requests from 2nd while it is in termination.

Let's say Container 1 depends on Container 2 and both the containers receive `SIGTERM` simultaneously and Container 2 stops quickly and all the inflight requests in Container 1 being dependent on Container 2 starts failing.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the containers are better fitted to running on two different pods (IMHO)

And adding a retry mechanism using code/servicemesh to make the application more resilient

For example https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#retries

Comment: The problem is with the latency that gets incurred when you go with multiple pods per container basis. I am looking specifically for a single-digit ms latency in this case which can only be possible if the dependent is localhost.

Answer (score 0):

By having **preStop lifecycle** configured on both the container 1 and 2. I have one solution.

Lets have a shared volume.

ex : /var directory

Let's have a file main.txt inside this shared folder.
Which will be visible in both the container and can be visible the real time modification from both the container.

pre-condition :
main.txt has to be created at the time of creating contianer 1 and removed at the time of deleting container 1.

preStop :

1. container 1 remove this main.txt file in preStop which is the last action before container 1 termination.
2. container 2 have loop in preStop to wait until the main.txt got deleted. Which will prefer your container 1 to be complete first.

Will this useful ?